# How to correctly space <td> content in email?

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I'm creating an email template for ActiveCampaign and I need to place 3 images in one row, next to each other, with 14px padding in-between.

I created a custom HTML block with table, but I can't position the images properly.

**What I wanted it to look like**

[image: What I wanted it to look like]

**What it looks like in the email client**

[image: What it looks like in the email client]

Email layout is set to be full-width, but the content is centered and takes 500px. Hence the table width set to 500px.

Anyone can tell me what's wrong?

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

<tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;">

        <table width="500px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0 auto;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td>
                   <a href=""><img style="padding: 0;" src="https://ac-image.s3.amazonaws.com/6/7/7/4/3/7/home/admin/new_email_templates/group-1.jpg?r=715459984">
                    </a>
                   </td>
                    <td>
                 <a href=""><img style="padding: 0;" src="https://ac-image.s3.amazonaws.com/6/7/7/4/3/7/home/admin/new_email_templates/group_2.jpg?r=1551841180">
                     </a>      
                  </td >
                  <td>
        <a href=""><img style="padding: 0;" src="https://ac-image.s3.amazonaws.com/6/7/7/4/3/7/home/admin/new_email_templates/group.jpg?r=269367714">
       </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</tr>
</td>
</table>
```

Comment: remove the inner table width and it will take the space of it's content and be centered in the parent td.  you may also need a bit of cell padding to create the gaps between the images.  If that doesn't work, then you may want to add width:500px to the style tag as some email clients will not use the width attribute

Comment: This works perfectly well on chrome browser. Also, you have validation issue in your HTML code. at the end before the table end tag, tr should close and not td

Comment: @Sonia True, in the browser it looks fine. But it seems that the email client makes tds wider.

Comment: @Dankos, I check in gmail client, it works perfect. Just correct the closing tags at the end and check the code again

Comment: @Pete Thank you.  Neither of the things you mentioned worked, unfortunately.